# Ошибка запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

В чем здесь ошибка

```
mysql_query("SELECT name, text, time FROM '$db_name' WHERE id > '$last_id'")
```

пишет

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\localhost\www\select_db.php on line 23
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''comments_soviet_independent' WHERE id > '3'' at line 1`

Если заменить `$db_name` на строчку `comments_soviet_independent`, все ок. При этом

```
$name_db == "comments_soviet_independent"  // равны
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

без кавычек попробуй

```
mysql_query("SELECT name, text, time FROM $db_name WHERE id > $last_id")
```